# App Constant in application

Tags: android

I created Listview and menu options in android application with App Constants to minimize the number of classes

Ex:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context=this;
        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,prgmNameList));
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
```

OnClickListener

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, First.class);
                intent.putExtra(AppConstants.MAIN_ACTIVITY_TAG,lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

        }
```

But i need apply app constants to Menu Options too 
But i don't know how to do that:

Here is the code for Menu Options

```
// create action options for options
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.news, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_about) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,Extras.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_advertise) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_contact) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_help) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

I want to do same as listview but for menu options.
Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Use string.xml .

Comment: please elaborate, i am confused

Comment: What exactly the problem is ? Do you want to use string constants in xml ?

Comment: i dont know how to use app constant for the menu options even with use of string. xml

Answer (score 0):

Just put your string in string.xml .

```
<string name="menu_name">Show result</string>
```

and you directly access it in xml .

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  tools:context=".ContainerActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_action_show"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:icon="@drawable/youricon"
    android:title="@string/menu_name"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

You can also access all resources using java code with context :

```
 String menu_name=getString(R.id.menu_name);
```